TikZ picture pie chart - Exclude labels for categories with 0
I need to display a pie chart with 5 categories but where some have a result of 0. But there is this annoying "0" showing up on the pie chart. How can I get rid of it? I suspect it's the 0 from the "Neither agree nor disagree" category. I either want to make it so 0 categories don't show up at all, or so I can hide just that one, but I haven't been able to find a resource to do it online. Thank you!
Image:

Code:
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\definecolor{ELMpos}{RGB}{178, 255, 102} % Light lime green
\definecolor{ROUNDneg}{RGB}{150, 54, 86} % Burgundy
\definecolor{ELMneg}{RGB}{229, 102, 102} % Soft red
\definecolor{ANON}{RGB}{102, 204, 178} % Mint green
\definecolor{CONCISE}{RGB}{224, 255, 255} % Pale cyan

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pie[
            text=legend,
            radius=2,
            color={ROUNDneg, ELMneg, ANON, ELMpos, CONCISE},
            sum=auto
        ]{
            0/Strongly disagree,
            2/Disagree,
            0/Neither agree nor disagree,
            7/Agree,
            10/Strongly agree
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}


\end{document}


Please always post a compilable [mre] including all the necessary packages and a class.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz sorry about that. Done!

You could redefine \pgfpie@slice to check if the number is > 0:
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\definecolor{ELMpos}{RGB}{178, 255, 102} % Light lime green
\definecolor{ROUNDneg}{RGB}{150, 54, 86} % Burgundy
\definecolor{ELMneg}{RGB}{229, 102, 102} % Soft red
\definecolor{ANON}{RGB}{102, 204, 178} % Mint green
\definecolor{CONCISE}{RGB}{224, 255, 255} % Pale cyan


\makeatletter
% args:
% #1: begin angle
% #2: end angle
% #3: number
% #4: label
% #5: explode
% #6: fill color
% #7: radius
% #8: center
\def\pgfpie@slice#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \pgfmathparse{0.5*(#1)+0.5*(#2)}
  \let\pgfpie@midangle\pgfmathresult

  \path (#8) -- ++({\pgfpie@midangle}:{#5}) coordinate (pgfpie@O);

  \pgfmathparse{(#7)+(#5)}
  \let\pgfpie@radius\pgfmathresult
  
  % slice
  \draw[line join=round,fill={#6},\pgfpie@style] (pgfpie@O) -- ++({#1}:{#7}) arc ({#1}:{#2}:{#7}) -- cycle;

  \pgfpie@ifchangedirection{%
    \pgfmathparse{min(((#1)-(#2)-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}
  }{%
    \pgfmathparse{min(((#2)-(#1)-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}
  }%
  
  \pgfmathparse{(max(\pgfmathresult,-0.5) + 0.8)*(#7)}
  \let\pgfpie@innerpos\pgfmathresult

  \pgfpie@ifx\pgfpie@text\pgfpie@text@inside{%
    % label and number together
    \path (pgfpie@O) -- ++({\pgfpie@midangle}:{\pgfpie@innerpos}) node[align=center]
    {\pgfpie@scalefont{#3}\pgfpie@labeltext{#4}\\\pgfpie@numbertext{#3}};
  }{%
    % label
    \pgfpie@ifhidelabel{}{%
      \pgfpie@iflegend{}{%
        \path (pgfpie@O) -- ++ ({\pgfpie@midangle}:{\pgfpie@radius})
        node[inner sep=0, \pgfpie@text={\pgfpie@midangle:#4}]{};
      }%
    }%

    % number
    \ifnum#3>0
      \path (pgfpie@O) -- ++({\pgfpie@midangle}:{\pgfpie@innerpos}) node
      {\pgfpie@scalefont{#3}\pgfpie@numbertext{#3}};
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pie[
            text=legend,
            radius=2,
            color={ROUNDneg, ELMneg, ANON, ELMpos, CONCISE},
            sum=auto
        ]{
            0/Strongly disagree,
            2/Disagree,
            0/Neither agree nor disagree,
            7/Agree,
            10/Strongly agree
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}


\end{document}


